# Are DetailsView /FormView enough rich for Edit and Insert?

Tags: asp.net, insert, detailsview, formview

I'm wondering are DetailsView/FormView and ObjectDataSource have enough capability for Inserting/Editing your records or not ?

Or better ask you Do you prefer use them or make your form by your own ?

Because some times it's not easy to use them for complicated task , On the other hand when you have a lot of fields , that's over killing make your form by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt you can use asp.net detailsview and formsview to edit, insert, display data. This makes it easier and faster to play around your data, if you are handy with it. Otherwise you may stumble with some typical odds, of which almost all are answered and you can find them over Internet. Conclusion: Once you get with formsview, detailsview they will be your favourite tools! That is what Microsoft wants of developers.

Still there are some points to remember: if you have forms with lots of controls and you need them interact with each other, you need to consider playing around the straight ways of formview, detailsview. In such case, you would feel very easy if you had created your own UI with necessary controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do.  Each of these has an insert/edit template.  You can make them work, and they work fine.  Have used them in my own applications.  Complicated tasks, formview should be able to handle because you have full control over the UI and layout.

If you have a large form, detailsview allows you to specify fields and allows the control to do the work (you simply specify the data and detailsview handles the form), but of course with a custom UI the formview is the way to go, and yes it can be tedious to have to create large forms...  but it's something we developers must do, either find or create a form builder control or create the UI markup ourselves.